# Given a locally free sheaf, compute its associated vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-vector-bundles

I have this situation, $r$ and $s$ are positive integers: we define $\mathcal{E}$ to be the vector bundle on $\mathbb{P}^s$ whose associated locally free sheaf is 
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^s} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^s}(1)^{r+1}.
$$
I would like to describe explicitly $\mathcal{E}$, how can I do it step-by-step?

I'm putting myself in the situation where $r=1$ and $s=2$, so $\mathcal{E}$ is the vector bundle associated to the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)^{2}$.

- Clearly $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ are the regular functions on $\mathbb{P}^2$, hence $\mathbb{C}$.
- $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)$ can be associated to the homogeneous polynomials of degree 1, hence $\mathbb{C}[x_0,x_1,x_2]_1$, so $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)^2=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(2)$ (am I right?) is associated to the homogeneous polynomials of degree 2, hence $\mathbb{C}[x_0,x_1,x_2]_2$.

Since $\dim \mathbb{C}[x_0,x_1,x_2]_2=6$ as a vector space, I expect that $\mathcal{E}$ is something locally as $U_i \times \mathbb{C}^7$ where $U_i=\{x_i \ne 0\}$ is the usual covering of $\mathbb{P}^2$. Am I right? But, how $\mathcal{E}$ looks globally?

Comment: You say that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ consists of the regular functions on $\mathbb{P}^2$, hence $\mathbb{C}$. This is not exactly true. The _global sections_ of that sheaf are constant, but this is not true for all opens $U\subseteq \Bbb{P}^2$. Also: what is $\mathcal{O}(1)^2$? Is this $\mathcal{O}(1)\otimes \mathcal{O}(1)$, or is it $\mathcal{O}(1)\oplus \mathcal{O}(1)$? If it is the former, then indeed $\mathcal{O}(1)\otimes \mathcal{O}(1)\cong \mathcal{O}(2)$. However, if it is the latter, then what you wrote is false, because $\mathcal{O}(1)\oplus \mathcal{O}(1)$ is rank $2$.